# Ionic 3 open new page over tab

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am developing an app that uses tab, For the sliding feature. Once launching the app users will be navigating to the home page. There on click of one Icon User will be navigating to Tabs page having two tabs "tab1" and "tab1". In tab1 I have Fab button on click of a fab button. It should go to the new page. (Not opening inside tab). So After researching, I got a solution to use.

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('AddreminderPage', {}, { animate: true });
```

But after navigating to a new page if I click hardware back button app is not redirecting to tab1 When I click hardware back button for the second time app redirects to home page.

**Expected behavior**

from new page when I click hardware back button the first time, the app should navigate to tab1 page on click hardware back button for the second time it should navigate to the home page

please help me 
Thanks,